# Get execution time without taking into account the not scheduled time

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I'm trying to measure the time in a loop in this way on Linux:

```
void Timer::run() {
    while ( isRunning() ) {
        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        doSomething();
        auto stop = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        auto waitingTime = tick - (stop - start);
        waitFor(waitingTime);
    }
}
```

It works but if while my program is executing `doSomething()` I stop the process using `kill -STOP` and then I resume the process using `kill -CONT` I can see that waitingTime includes the time where the program was suspended. Is it possible to retrieve only the real execution time?

Comment: Under Linux, you could check the `/proc/$PID/stat` (where `$PID` is your process's pid_t from `getpid()`).

Comment: @Eljay I would be happy to use something more portable and robust, reading a proc file is not really ideal, I'd like to read some proposal however, it's the reason why I posted :)

Comment: I don't think Standard C++ provides an abstraction API for processes.  Possibly [Boost Process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/process.html) may fill that gap, but I'm not terribly familiar with that part of Boost.